# soap call error

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to call a function via a SOAP webservice. The following code is run:

```
  $return_soap = $this->soap->__soapCall($soap_function, $params);
```

I have also tryed:

```
$return_soap = call_user_func_array(array($this->soap,$soap_function),$params);
```

The headers are good, and i'm sending the following parameters:

```
$params = array('customer_info'=>array_values( 'name'=>'Stephen de Tester',              
          'i_parent'=>12695,
          'iso_4217'=>'EU',
          'i_customer_type'=>1,
          'opening_balance'=>'10.00',
          'i_customer_class'=>1));
```

i have tryed it without array_values and a bunch of other combinations. I always get the following message:

```
( [error] => SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'customer_info' property )
```

However if i try a webservice call without parameters it all seems to work perfectly...

Could you guys help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you supply the url to the WSDL file for the service? I'm not quite sure from the error but it's either saying that you haven't supplied a customer_info property or that you've supplied a customer_info property on a method that doesn't accept that property. Either way a peek at the WSDL should help make it clearer.

Comment: I forgot a tag there i believe, weird because it used to be optional. i believe they might have changed the webservice